# How to apply shader to each shapes at their location?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sfml

I am playing with SFML and wrote a minimal program that draws a line behind the cursor.

I would like to make this line glow so I wrote a minimal shader that I apply to each line vertex. However, the maximum number of uniforms is about 4096. Instead, I would like to "run" my shader at each vertex position. Is there a better way other than using a global fragment and passing each position as uniforms?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const float winW = 1000;
    const float winH = 1000;
    const int tail_length = 100;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(winW, winH), "SFML");

    sf::VertexArray lines(sf::LinesStrip, tail_length);
    boost::circular_buffer<sf::Vector2i> tail(tail_length);

    sf::Clock clk;
    clk.restart();

    sf::Vector2i old_mouse_pos = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);

    // std::fill(tail.begin(), tail.end(), sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.create(winW, winH);
    sf::Sprite spr(tex);
    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile("glow.glsl", sf::Shader::Fragment);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        shader.setUniform("resolution", sf::Vector2f(40, 40));
        sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
        if (old_mouse_pos != mousePos)
            tail.push_back(mousePos);

        old_mouse_pos = sf::Vector2i(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

        sf::Vector2f v[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < tail.size(); i++)
        {
            v[i] = sf::Vector2f(tail[i].x, tail[i].y- 2* winH / 2);
            lines[i].position = sf::Vector2f(tail[i].x, tail[i].y);
            lines[i].color = sf::Color(255, 0, 0, i * 255 / tail_length);
        }
        shader.setUniformArray("tail", v, tail.size());
        window.clear();
        window.draw(spr, &shader);
        window.draw(lines);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Here the shader:

```
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 tail[100];

void main(void) {
    vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    float d = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        vec2 u = tail[i];
        vec2 q;
        q.x = p.x - u.x / resolution.x;
        q.y = p.y + u.y / resolution.y;
        float dist = pow(1.0/length(q) * 0.1, 1.5);
        d += dist;
    }
    vec3 col = d * vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.25);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0 - exp( -col ), 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Could you send your tail vector as a buffer to the vertex shader instead? This is how a mesh is rendered in general.

Comment: @kali, you mean by a array of uniforms?

Comment: Probably with some blending mode - especially if you can tolerate changing the blending mode. Looks like your shader is doing some multiplicative blending but "upside down" so it multiplies towards 1. Maybe you can do usual multiplicative blending, then run a postprocessing step to subtract all the colours from 1. Then, each glow point can be rendered as a separate triangle/quad.

Comment: @nowox I don't quite get why you're sending your tail vector like this to the shader. Normally, you allocate a block of memory on the GPU (a VBO = Vertex Buffer Object) and send your vertex array (i.e., the tail vector) to the vertex shader. The vertex shader then takes in each position of the tail vector and might perform some operations on each position before being sent to the fragment shader.